# Pointer event combine hover css

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a image that needs preventing people from saving or drag so I use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

but then I also want to add hover effect zoom like:

```
transform: scale(1.5);
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `pointer-events:none;` on the img, but wrap it in another element to trigger the hover action.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}

.image-wrapper:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

img {
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrapper"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></div>
```

Comment: I thought of this but the hover effect on the div.image-wrapper cause the div itself to zoom out, what I want is the image to zoom out but still contained inside the div

Comment: Not necessarily - look at the format in here and run the snippet. `image-wrapper:hover img` is the css selector, meaning when the wrapper div is hovered over, apply styles to the img it contains.

Comment: I didn't know you can use hover on img with .image-wrapper, worked like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, `pointer-events: none` will stop the element reacting to any mouse movements or clicks at all, which isn't what you want.

To prevent dragging, you can just add the `draggable="false"` attribute to your image.

To cancel clicks, you can add an event listener to click and then call `event.preventDefault()` or `return false`. The quick and dirty way to do this is:

`<img draggable="false" onclick="return false;"/>`

There are [much neater and nicer ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) of attaching javascript to your elements, though.

It's important to know that disabling clicking and dragging will not prevent someone who really wants to save your image from saving it - and there's not really anything you can do if someone is *really* determined. If the user can see the image, the user can save the image. It might make it slightly more annoying, which might be enough for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the neat answer Beenjamin, although I was looking for a solution with pure css

Comment: No problem! My feeling here is that CSS is a 'display' layer, and so, while you can control the behaviour with it to some extent, it's more robust to use the browser's native behaviours in the HTML itself where possible.